# Despite using Infer Constraints, my Text Field, and Button aren't showing in their repsective locations in preview and output

Tags: java, android

I have tried using Infer Constraints but the output is very bizarre on the emulator as compared to the preview.

I have tried using the infer constraints button

[image: Preview and Emulator Image shown below]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text"/>
```

Comment: It gives the following error "Unexpected text found in layout file: "app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name"/>" less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Layout resource files should only contain elements and attributes. Any XML text content found in the file is likely accidental (and potentially dangerous if the text resembles XML and the developer believes the text to be functional)  Issue id: ExtraText"

Comment: Put above code inside Constraint Layout and add= xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". If it does not work then post your XML code and build.gradle file.